# Finding an element's location in a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find a specific elements position in a jQuery collection.

For example in a collection of a elements I need to know the numeric position of the element with the "active" class.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"></a></li>
</ul>
```

I assumed using index would be the way to go but the following returns 0 no matter what the location of active.

```
$('ul li a').index('.active');
```

Is there any simple way to do what this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('ul li a.active').index();
```

Note that even by using correct syntax this code always returns `0` as there is only one anchor link within li tags, you can find the index of parent li element instead.

```
$('ul li:has(a.active)').index();
```

Comment: This returns 0. It's the first item in the collection <li></li> I'm assuming?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$('ul li a').each(function(i) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) console.log(i);
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LHHQa/)**

Or

```
console.log ($('ul li:has(a.active)').index() );​
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do :

```
 $('ul li a').index($('ul li a.active'));
```

If you pass a DOM element or jQuery object to `index` it returns the position of that element/object in the original collection.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z6UNP/1/) for the sake of completeness

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$('li').index($('.active').parent())
```

Answer (score -1):

$("ul li a").each(function(i){

```
if($(this).hasClass("active")){
 alert(i)        
}
```

});​

i hope it will solve your problem